# Tarry vs Linger difference

Tags: word-difference

Is there a difference between "**to tarry**" and "**to linger**" when speaking about "*staying in some place for a long time*".

Comment: ***Tarry***:  (old use or literary) to stay in a place, especially when you ought to leave; to delay coming to or going from a place. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tarry - ***Linger*** [intransitive]  to stay somewhere for longer because you do not want to leave; to spend a long time doing something - https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/linger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word **tarry** has very little currency in contemporary American English outside of literary works. It was used far more often in 18th and 19th centuries than now even there.  The predominant meaning is "to delay action, or to remain where one is, and thereby fall behind a desired or appropriate rate of progress on a journey, errand, or course of action".

The word **linger** has considerably more currency than **tarry** does in AmE, but I would imagine—shooting from the hip—that maybe one or two in ten speakers actually use it today in conversation.  It means to not leave a place, to stick around for a while longer. Unlike **tarry** it does not have the implication that appropriate action or progress is delayed thereby, but there is the notion that an appropriate time of departure has passed.  It, too, is often found in literary works, especially in bodice-rippers, where lips linger.

> His lips lingered on hers.

You would not say

> His lips tarried on hers.

or

> His lips loitered on hers.

Comment: So you can tarry in progress or action but linger in space?

Comment: Yes, you've got it.